# PHPExcel/phpSpeadsheet Converting Integer to Time

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am using the new version of PHPExcel, phpSpreadsheet and one of my cell's require a time value based on an integer, for example: I have an integer that equals to 30 (meaning 30 seconds). I want to get that into my cell and output as 0:30. Problem i am having is Excel is removing the trailing 0.

I have tried converting it to a string using

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('E20', $time, \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

but with no success, have also tried with the setFormatCode() but no luck either, always outputs 030 as 03. Also need a way to turn 030 into 0:30 if possible.

Any help on this will be appreciated cheers.